# Counting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: users, questions and actions. These hold data to do with users answering questions on a tutorial site. Once they have answered enough questions they move on to a new section of questions. They continually request questions from the pool of unanswered questions, in random order, until they have done them all.

If a user does not get enough questions correct for the section, and runs out of total questions in the database for that particular section, my code needs to loop back around and gives them all of the sections questions again, in random order.

Up until that point I was using this query,

```
    SELECT action_int
    FROM actions
    WHERE user_id = '".$this->id."'
    AND action_type = 'given_question'
    AND action_details = 'weekly'
    AND action_int IN (
        SELECT action_int
        FROM actions
        WHERE user_id = '".$this->id."'
        AND action_type = 'answered_question'
        )
    AND action_int IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM questions
        WHERE section_id = '".$this->current_section."'
        )
```

action_int is the question id stored in the action table. This will return all questions answered, in the users current section, but not repeats if the code has looped back around.

So, my first approach to solving this was, I want to query the db so that I get out every question the user has answered, count how many times he has answered that unique question (in case they have looped around all the questions before), and randomly select a question id from the values where count is at a minimum (MIN()).

I have been trying,

```
SELECT q.id, a.count
FROM questions q

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    action_int AS id, count(action_int) AS 'count'
FROM
    actions
WHERE
    action_type = 'answered_question'
GROUP BY action_int) a
ON  a.id = q.id
```

which returns,

```
id  count

14  2
16  3
17  3
11  null
13  null
15  null
18  1
12  1
19  null
```

which is generally what I am after.

So questions,

1. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe so that if a question hasn't
   been answered yet it returns 0 for the count instead of null?
2. If I only want to count answered questions which are in the users current section (stored in questions as section_id and users as current_section), how can I return the columns containing only [id, count] of questions from a section number?